# FAIL - Application at context path /dms could not be started

Tags: apache, tomcat, deployment, tomcat8

Deployment is successful but I can't start the service, I really don't know why it won't start, the catalina log isn't really helping me solve the problem, I checked my web.xml I don't see anything that could cause the errors.

here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.REPOSITORY_CONFIG_FILE</param-name>
    <param-value>/cmis-repository.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <description>Victor - Document Management System</description>
  <display-name>Victor DMS</display-name>
  <!-- Location of the XML file that defines the root application context 
        Applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <!-- Useful in development mode to slow down the uploads in fast networks. 
            Put the number of milliseconds to sleep in each block received in the server. 
            false or 0, means don't use slow uploads -->
    <param-name>slowUploads</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <!-- Timeout used when uploading files (milliseconds) -->
    <param-name>noDataTimeout</param-name>
    <param-value>60000</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>statusEnabledOnHosts</param-name>
      <param-value>localhost</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.logicaldoc.web.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.logicaldoc.web.SessionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <!-- mappings -->
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <!-- Application initializer -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.logicaldoc.web.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- Loads the root application context of this web app at startup. Use 
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext) to access 
        it anywhere in the web application, outside of the framework. The root context 
        is the parent of all servlet-specific contexts. This means that its beans 
        are automatically available in these child contexts, both for getBean(name) 
        calls and (external) bean references. -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.CmisRepositoryContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- This is the default servlet, it puts files in session -->
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadresource</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.DocumentResourceUpload</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SecurityService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.SecurityServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.SystemServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>InfoService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.InfoServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SearchEngineService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.SearchEngineServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DocumentService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.DocumentServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GarbageData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.GarbageDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FolderService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.FolderServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SearchService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.SearchServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TagService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.TagServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SettingService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.SettingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SetupService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.SetupServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TemplateService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.TemplateServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessageService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.MessageServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ContactService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.service.ContactServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DropboxService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.dropbox.DropboxServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TagsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.TagsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GroupsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.GroupsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UsersData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.UsersDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SessionsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.SessionsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FoldersData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.FoldersDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MenuesData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.MenuesDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DocumentsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.DocumentsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LinksData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.LinksDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DiscussionsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.DiscussionsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BookmarksData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.BookmarksDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PostsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.PostsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>EventsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.EventsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>VersionsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.VersionsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DocumentHistoryData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.DocumentHistoryDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FolderHistoryData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.FolderHistoryDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserHistoryData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.UserHistoryDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TemplatesData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.TemplatesDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SavedSearchesData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.gui.common.server.MockSavedSearchesDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DropboxData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.dropbox.DropboxDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExtendedAttributeOptionsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.ExtendedAttributeOptionsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Preview</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.DocumentPreview</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TicketDownload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.TicketDownload</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PswRecovery</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.PswRecovery</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExportZip</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.ExportZip</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RightsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.RightsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TasksData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.TasksDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ParsersData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.ParsersDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessagesData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.MessagesDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LanguagesData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.LanguagesDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FeedMessageData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.FeedMessageDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DuplicatesData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.gui.common.server.MockDuplicatesDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DocumentNotesData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.DocumentNotesDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Log</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.LogDownload</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ContactsData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.web.data.ContactsDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.webservice.WebserviceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Cmis</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.cmis.CmisServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>callContextHandler</param-name>
      <param-value>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.shared.BasicAuthCallContextHandler</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Webdav</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.logicaldoc.webdav.web.WebdavServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>resource-path-prefix</param-name>
      <param-value>/webdav</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>resource-config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gupld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadresource</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadresource</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SecurityService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/security</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SettingService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/setting</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/system</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InfoService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/info</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InfoService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/setup/info</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SearchEngineService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/searchengine</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DocumentService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/document</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GarbageData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/garbage.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SetupService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/setup/setup</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FolderService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/folder</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SearchService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/search</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TagService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/tag</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TemplateService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/template</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessageService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/message</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ContactService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/contact</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DropboxService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontend/dropbox</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TagsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/tags.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GroupsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/groups.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UsersData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/users.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SessionsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/sessions.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FoldersData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/folders.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MenuesData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/menues.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DocumentsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/documents.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LinksData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/links.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BookmarksData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/bookmarks.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DiscussionsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/discussions.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PostsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/posts.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EventsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/events.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VersionsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/versions.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DocumentHistoryData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/documenthistory.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FolderHistoryData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/folderhistory.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserHistoryData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/userhistory.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TemplatesData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/templates.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessagesData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/messages.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RightsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/rights.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TasksData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/tasks.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ParsersData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/parsers.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LanguagesData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/languages.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FeedMessageData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/feedmessage.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DuplicatesData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/duplicates.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DocumentNotesData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/documentnotes.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ContactsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/contacts.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DropboxData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/dropbox.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExtendedAttributeOptionsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/extoptions.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Preview</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/preview</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TicketDownload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download-ticket</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PswRecovery</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pswrecovery</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExportZip</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/zip-export</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Log</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/log</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- Welcome files -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Cmis</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/cmis/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Webdav</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webdav/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>frontend.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <!-- Human readable errors -->
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
      <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
      <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Setup only allowed after authentication</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Setup</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/setup.jsp</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/setup/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Sessions management only allowed after
            authentication</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Sessions</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/sessions.jsp</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/sessions/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>SETUP Login</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if both mysql and tomcat is running on same port number.If yes change the mysql port number.It worked out for me.